# WPF how to clear the texbox content in list view using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using below code and MVVM observable, but "Clear" button **not** clears the content of text boxes.

What I need to do here?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Credentials, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="User Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" Width="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Password">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" Width="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearTextBoxCommand}" Width="150"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Credential> _credentials;

    public RelayCommand ClearTextBoxCommand { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Credential> Credentials
    {
        get => _credentials;
        set
        {
            if (value == _credentials)
                return;

            _credentials = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        var data = new List<Credential> {new Credential {UserName = "user1", Password = "password1"}};
        _credentials = new ObservableCollection<Credential>(data);

        ClearTextBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearTextBox);
    }

    private void ClearTextBox()
    {
        var data = new List<Credential> { new Credential { UserName = "", Password = "" } };
        _credentials = new ObservableCollection<Credential>(data);
        MessageBox.Show("clear done!");
    }
}

public class Credential
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In case you always only create a new collection instance (as in the accepted answer), it isn't necessary to use ObservableCollection. A simple `List<Credential>` would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credentials *property* has notification about change in setter:

```
public ObservableCollection<Credential> Credentials
{
    get => _credentials;
    set
    {
        if (value == _credentials)
            return;

        _credentials = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

so if you need to change that collection, use *property*, not _credentials *field*

not `_credentials = new ObservableCollection<Credential>(data);`, but

```
private void ClearTextBox()
{
    var data = new List<Credential> { new Credential { UserName = "", Password = "" } };
    Credentials = new ObservableCollection<Credential>(data);
    MessageBox.Show("clear done!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Credentials property instead of _credentials field is mandatory. But you do not have to assign a complete new ObservableCollection. Just clear the old one and add a new Credentials object.

```
private void ClearTextBox()
{
    Credentials.Clear();
    Credentials.Add(new Credential { UserName = "", Password = "" });
    MessageBox.Show("clear done!");
}
```

Comment: If you use the Credentials property like this, you wouldn't even need to fire a change notofication. It could simply be a readonly property like `public ObservableCollection<Credential> Credentials { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Credential>();`

Answer (score -4):

This is working at my Application

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PRWSolution.UI.View.MachineView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.View"
         xmlns:language="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.Properties.Langs"
         xmlns:setting="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.Properties"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         DataContext="{Binding Machine, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
         xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
         xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
         TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
         Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
         TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
         TextElement.FontSize="14"
         FontFamily="{materialDesign:MaterialDesignFont}">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <!--Toolbar for interaction-->
                <ToolBarTray Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}" ClipToBounds="False">
                        <Button x:Name="SaveMachine" ToolTip="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ContentSave" />
                        </Button>

                        <Button x:Name="EditeMachine" ToolTip="Edit" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Edit" />
                        </Button>

                        <Button x:Name="DeleteMachine" ToolTip="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete" />
                        </Button>

                        <Separator />

                        <Button x:Name="ClearForm" ToolTip="Clear Form">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="LayersClear" />
                        </Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>

                <ToolBarTray Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}" ClipToBounds="False">
                        <Button x:Name="ExportMachine" ToolTip="Export" Click="ExportMachine_Click">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TableExport" />
                        </Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <!--Card for input database information-->
        <materialDesign:Card Margin="5">
            <StackPanel>

                <!--Expander general machine information-->
                <Expander Header="{x:Static language:Lang.ExpMachineData }" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtMachineID" Text="{Binding MachineID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgMachineID}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtCustomerID" Text="{Binding CustomerID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCustomerId}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCustomerName" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedValuePath="ClientName" SelectedValue="{Binding CustomerName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding MachineCustomer.ClientDataContext, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" DisplayMemberPath="ClientName"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Customer Name" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtCity" Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCity}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtCountry" Text="{Binding Country, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCountry}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>

                <Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

                <!--Expander general part info-->
                <Expander Header="Part Information" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtPartName" Text="{Binding PartName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Part Name" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtPartNumber" Text="{Binding PartNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Part Number" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtProject" Text="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Project" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>

                <Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

                <!--Expander for Machine Serials-->
                <Expander Header="{x:Static language:Lang.ExpMachineSerials}" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtSpindleC1" Text="{Binding SpindleC1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgSpindleC1}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtSpindleC2" Text="{Binding SpindleC2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgSpindleC2}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtHoningHead" Text="{Binding HoningHead, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHoningHead}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>

                <Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

                <!--Expander for Softwareversion-->
                <Expander Header="{x:Static language:Lang.ExpSoftwareVersion}" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtNCVersion" Text="{Binding NCVersion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgNCVersion}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtHMIVersion" Text="{Binding HMIVersion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHMIVersion}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtHRIVersion" Text="{Binding HRIVersion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHRIVersion}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtAHSVersion" Text="{Binding AHSVersion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static language:Lang.DgAHSVersion}" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>

        <!--Database datagrid-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="MachineDataGrid" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxHeight="700" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MachineSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MachineDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </ie:EventTrigger>
            </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgMachineID}" Binding="{Binding MachineID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCustomerId}" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCustomerName}" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCity}" Binding="{Binding City}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgCountry}" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Name" Binding="{Binding PartName}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Number" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Project" Binding="{Binding Project}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgSpindleC1}" Binding="{Binding SpindleC1}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgSpindleC2}" Binding="{Binding SpindleC2}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHoningHead}" Binding="{Binding HoningHead}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgNCVersion}" Binding="{Binding NCVersion}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHMIVersion}" Binding="{Binding HMIVersion}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgHRIVersion}" Binding="{Binding HRIVersion}"/>
                <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static language:Lang.DgAHSVersion}" Binding="{Binding AHSVersion}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MachineViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    #region  public statments Textbox text

    //Public statments to get textbox text
    public string MachineID { get; set; }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }

    public string SpindleC1 { get; set; }

    public string SpindleC2 { get; set; }

    public string HoningHead { get; set; }

    public string NCVersion { get; set; }

    public string HMIVersion { get; set; }

    public string HRIVersion { get; set; }

    public string AHSVersion { get; set; }
    #endregion

    //DialogService
    private IDialogService _dialogService;

    //Operation button for save, update, delete, selection changed and print
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ClearCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    //observable collection for machine model
    public ObservableCollection<Machine> DataContext { get; set; }

    private Machine machineSelectedItem;
    public Machine MachineSelectedItem
    {
        get { return machineSelectedItem; }
        set { machineSelectedItem = value; }
    }

    public object MachineDataGrid { get; set; }


    public List<MachineClient> cmbclientDetails;

    //PRWContext for general use
    private PRWContext context = new PRWContext();

    public MachineViewModel()
    {
        //Commands for save, update, delete and print
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteSaveCommand());
        UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteUpdateCommand());
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteDeleteCommand());
        ClearCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteClearCommand());
        SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteSelectionChangedCommand());

        //Load the data from PRW Database to datagrid
        LoadData();

        //Normelly done with dependency injection
        _dialogService = new DialogService();
    }



    //execute save
    private void ExecuteSaveCommand()
    {
        Machine machine = new Machine
        {
            //Machine data
            MachineID = MachineID,
            CustomerID = CustomerID,
            CustomerName = CustomerName,
            City = City,
            Country = Country,

            //Part data
            PartName = PartName,
            PartNumber = PartNumber,
            Project = Project,

            //Serial data
            SpindleC1 = SpindleC1,
            SpindleC2 = SpindleC2,
            HoningHead = HoningHead,

            //Softwareversion data
            NCVersion = NCVersion,
            HMIVersion = HMIVersion,
            HRIVersion = HRIVersion,
            AHSVersion = AHSVersion
        };

        context.Machines.Add(machine);
        context.SaveChanges();

        ClearContent();
    }

    //execute update
    private void ExecuteUpdateCommand()
    {
        Machine machine = context.Machines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.MachineID == MachineID);

        machine.CustomerID = CustomerID;
        machine.CustomerName = CustomerName;
        machine.City = City;
        machine.Country = Country;
        machine.PartName = PartName;
        machine.PartNumber = PartNumber;
        machine.Project = Project;
        machine.SpindleC1 = SpindleC1;
        machine.SpindleC2 = SpindleC2;
        machine.HoningHead = HoningHead;
        machine.NCVersion = NCVersion;
        machine.HMIVersion = HMIVersion;
        machine.HRIVersion = HRIVersion;
        machine.AHSVersion = AHSVersion;

        context.Machines.AddOrUpdate(machine);
        context.SaveChanges();
        ClearContent();
    }

    //execute delete
    private void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
    {
        if (machineSelectedItem != null)
        {
            var dialog = new YesNoDialogViewModel("Question", "Your are Sure to Delete the Record?");
            var result = _dialogService.OpenDialog(dialog);
            if (result == DialogResults.Yes)
            {
                Machine machine = context.Machines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.MachineID == MachineID);
                context.Machines.Remove(machine);
                context.SaveChanges();
                ClearContent();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var dialog = new AlertDialogViewModel("Attention", "Please select a Record!");
            var result = _dialogService.OpenDialog(dialog);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

    }

    //execute clear
    private void ExecuteClearCommand()
    {
        ClearContent();
    }

    // Execute selection changed
    private void ExecuteSelectionChangedCommand()
    {
        if(machineSelectedItem != null)
        {
            MachineID = machineSelectedItem.MachineID?.ToString() ?? "";
            CustomerID = machineSelectedItem.CustomerID?.ToString() ?? "";
            CustomerName = machineSelectedItem.CustomerName?.ToString() ?? "";
            City = machineSelectedItem.City?.ToString() ?? "";
            Country = machineSelectedItem.Country?.ToString() ?? "";
            PartName = machineSelectedItem.PartName?.ToString() ?? "";
            PartNumber = machineSelectedItem.PartNumber?.ToString() ?? "";
            Project = machineSelectedItem.Project?.ToString() ?? "";
            SpindleC1 = machineSelectedItem.SpindleC1?.ToString() ?? "";
            SpindleC2 = machineSelectedItem.SpindleC2?.ToString() ?? "";
            HoningHead = machineSelectedItem.HoningHead?.ToString() ?? "";
            NCVersion = machineSelectedItem.NCVersion?.ToString() ?? "";
            HMIVersion = machineSelectedItem.HMIVersion?.ToString() ?? "";
            HRIVersion = machineSelectedItem.HRIVersion?.ToString() ?? "";
            AHSVersion = machineSelectedItem.AHSVersion?.ToString() ?? "";
        }
        else
        {
            machineSelectedItem = null;
        }


    }

    //Load data from database to grid
    private void LoadData()
    {
        context.Machines.Load();
        this.DataContext = context.Machines.Local;
    }

    //Clear textboxes
    private void ClearContent()
    {
        MachineID = string.Empty;
        CustomerID = string.Empty;
        CustomerName = string.Empty;
        City = string.Empty;
        PartName = string.Empty;
        PartNumber = string.Empty;
        Project = string.Empty;
        Country = string.Empty;
        SpindleC1 = string.Empty;
        SpindleC2 = string.Empty;
        HoningHead = string.Empty;
        NCVersion = string.Empty;
        HMIVersion = string.Empty;
        HRIVersion = string.Empty;
        AHSVersion = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: how `UserName` and `Password` coming here? could you please post your full code?

Comment: I am using `foreach (var c in _credentials)
            {
                c.UserName = string.Empty;
                c.Password = string.Empty;
            }`

Comment: My context is different. I have textbox inside listview and listview is binded with observables. This will not work